# What risks exist if I work in a C# shop and attempt to write F# just to rely on ILSpy for conversion?

Tags: f#, inline, cil, decompiler, ilspy

What risks are involved if I work in a C# shop and I attempt to write a feature in F# and then rely on ILSpy to translate the F# source code to a C# representation?

Comment: You will most certainly have unreadable and unmaintainable C# code

Comment: This blog post has many good ideas on low-risk ways of starting with F# at work: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work.html Using ILSpy to convert F# to C# is definitely _not_ one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would very strongly recommend against doing this.

- F# code that has been decompiled into C# tends to be extremely verbose and unreadable.  It will be near impossible for anyone who doesn't possess a copy of the original F# code to understand or maintain.
- Functional code gives you opportunities for code reuse that you wouldn't have in an OO language.  The C# code produced by decompiling probably wouldn't offer (m)any avenues of reuse beyond the boundaries of your decompiled F#.
- What's idiomatic in F# sometimes isn't in C#, that's particularly true after an intermediate stage of decompilation.  The code would likely not pass a review process.
- Units of measure and `inline` functions with static type constraints are both features of the F# compiler rather something provided by .NET.  You might gain *some* advantage from them by using the decompiled C# directly but any modifications made to the C# source wouldn't be checked for e.g. dimensional correctness.

I would also second Tomas' suggestion of having a read through this article: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work/

I would suggest, however, that it could be worth having a conversation with your team/manager(s) about the possibility of introducing F# at your workplace.

My personal experience of using F# commercially is that development time often tends to be shorter (sometimes substantially) compared to the same project done in C# and it's usually easier to verify and test the result.  These are advantages that are very appealing commercially.

Comment: Thanks InnerLight.Should I first write test automation support with this language before asking permission to implement business solutions with it?

Comment: @ScottNimrod It's tough for me to give you advise about how you should proceed when it comes to your company, ultimately you know your team better than I do.  That said, anything you can do to demonstrate the business value of using F# is going to help your case.  If you think it's going to be a hard sell, I would hold off until there is a situation where you know that FP/F# is really going to excel.  In some cases, it's really pretty obvious it's a better choice for expressing a particular problem, in other cases that might be less obvious to those with little to no F# experience.